# Getting Record ID after saving with SubSonic 2.2

Tags: subsonic, primary-key

How do I get the Record ID (Primary Key) immediately after saving a record? I have the ID column as auto generated. I need to pass the ID to another object as a "Foreign Key" before saving that object.

Currently I do

```
Product.Save()
```

Can't I do

```
int id = Product.Save()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply do

```
Product.Save();
int id = Product.ID; //or whatever your ID column is
```